# Join 2 Pandas dataframes on specific columns accounting for nan

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 pandas DataFrames `dfA` and `dfB` with X and Y columns and rows.

I need to append `dfB` on `dfA`, creating `dfC`. I need the appending to be on columns with column names in both `dfA` and `dfB`.

Moreover, if column name in `dfA` does not appear in `dfB`, then `dfC` should contain Nan values.

---

To simplify,

`dfA` looks like,

```
    c1   c2   c3
0  AX1  AX2  AX3
1  AY1  AY2  AY3
2  AZ1  AZ2  AZ3
```

while `dfB` looks like,

```
    c1   c2   c4
0  BX1  BX2  BX3
1  BY1  BY2  BY3
2  BZ1  BZ2  BZ3
```

such that `dfC` should look like,

```
    c1   c2   c3
0  AX1  AX2  AX3
1  AY1  AY2  AY3
2  AZ1  AZ2  AZ3
3  BX1  BX2  Nan
4  BY1  BY2  Nan
5  BZ1  BZ2  Nan
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) and filter columns of `dfA`:

```
df = pd.concat([dfA, dfB])[dfA.columns]
```

Or filter columns by [`intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.intersection.html):

```
cols = dfA.columns.intersection(dfB.columns)
df = pd.concat([dfA, dfB[cols]])
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
pd.concat([dfA,dfB[['c1','c2']]])
```

To Avoid Hard coding columns

try this,

```
inter=list(set(dfA.columns)&set(dfB.columns))
print pd.concat([dfA,dfB[inter]])
```

Comment: Thanks, but with @jezrael's answer I don't have to check column names.